# $\exists f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ continuous, non-constant, with uncountably many extrema?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, examples-counterexamples, supremum-and-infimum

I couldnt think of any; by intuition I  don't think any can exist, but I can't figure out how to prove it.  If it existed then the set of extrema would have to be uncountable but I think this might somehow violate continuity.

Comment: Please take the time to write your posts in coherent English. This is not a text message.

Comment: I don't think "$\Bbb R$ is dense" makes sense.

Comment: o ok i removed it

Comment: @FlybyNight chill out, it isn't a Fields medal acceptance speech either

Comment: @Frank I realise that. It seems that the post has been changed since I commented. The original post would have been criticised if it were a child's homework. I personally feel that the OP should make a post legible and clear. If they show such little care and respect to their post then they are, IMHO, showing little care and respect to the community. Perhaps I'm being old-fashioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a closed uncountable set without interior points, such as [the Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) $C$. The distance function 
$$f(x) = \min\{|x-y|:y\in C\}$$
is continuous, not constant on any interval, and has a minimum at every point of $C$.